# How to define custom lock to spring boot schedular

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, locking

I have 2 Schedulers

Scheduler 1 :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * ? * *")
@ScheduledLock(name = "scheular1", lockAtLeastFor = "PT10S", lockAtMostFor = "PT30M")
void task1() {
    processSomething();
}
```

Schedular 2:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * ? * *")
@ScheduledLock(name = "scheular1", lockAtLeastFor = "PT10S", lockAtMostFor = "PT30M")
void task1() {
    processSomething();
}
```

DataSoruces:

```
@Bean("dataSource1")
DataSource dataSoruce1() {
     createHikariDataSoruce1();
}

@Bean(dataSoruce2) 
DataSource dataSoruce2() {
     createHikariDataSoruce2();
}
```

And Lock Providers:

```
@Bean
LockProvider lockProvider1(@Qualifier("dataSoruce1") DataSoruce dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}

@Bean
LockProvider lockProvider2(@Qualifier("dataSoruce2") DataSoruce dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}
```

I want both of these scheulars to use different locks and connection pool. How to do this?
Such that scheular 1 uses dataSoruce1 and lockProvider1. Similarly for schedular2 uses dataSoruce2 and lockProvider2.